# Avoid Refreshing on Databound Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am working on a metrics screen that will display several charts based on different groups in a database. Part of it uses a function that hides selected charts until the user clicks to display them.

The problem is this: I'm using a Databind on the dropdownlist, so every time I select a new group, the page refreshes and everything returns to its default state.

My question is this: Is there a way that I can avoid refreshing the page every time I select a new option from the dropdown list? If so, how? If not, is there a better way to create the dropdownlist and attach values to it? If I set `AppendDataBoundItems` to `false`, then I always get the selected value as the first item in the list.

Here's my code for the dropdownlist:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="MinistryDropdown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Selection_Change" AutoPostback="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"/>
```

Then C# code behind it is this:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    MinistryDropdown.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
    MinistryDropdown.DataTextField = "Description";
    MinistryDropdown.DataValueField = "Description";
    MinistryDropdown.DataBind();

...other code here...
}
ICollection CreateDataSource(){
    DataTable Ministries = new DataTable();

    Ministries = oDatabase.GetData(@"SELECT DISTINCT B.Description
        FROM tblInvolvement AS A LEFT JOIN tblMinistries AS B
        ON A.Activity = B.MinistryID");

    DataView dv = new DataView(Ministries);
    return dv;
}
```

Comment: If your concerned about the page refresh, just use ajax.

Comment: I may be way off the mark, but is the problem that you don't have a `if (!IsPostBack)`?  It sounds like you're saying everything refreshes and you don't want it to, right?

Comment: That's correct. If I use that, though, all of the rest of the charts disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the ASP.NET UpdatePanel. Just wrap your DropDownList in it, and it should works. Here is a quick example that I didn't test.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="MinistryDropdown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Selection_Change" AutoPostback="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On a final note, you will soon find out the limits of this solution, and later you might  prefer to use Javascript instead.

Comment: Alright, so I did that, but now the chart is not updating. I debugged through the code, and the c# runs fine (it gets all the correct values) when I change the dropdown selection, but the chart does not display the change. I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: But, it is letting the hidden areas stay hidden, so thank you. I'll work it out from here and probably use JS or try a different way from the C#.

Comment: Did you try putting your chart into the UpdatePanel as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are rebinding the data on Page_Load but you are not checking if `!IsPostBack` in other words, your code should look like this:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       MinistryDropdown.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
       MinistryDropdown.DataTextField = "Description";
       MinistryDropdown.DataValueField = "Description";
       MinistryDropdown.DataBind();

      ...other code here...
   }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that earlier, but then my charts disappeared when I selected a new value on the dropdownlist. I'm not very familiar with ASP, so I may be building the entire thing wrong.